# F# - Array.Parallel module not accessible

Tags: module, f#

I can access the `Array.Parallel` module in F# Interactive but not when compiling.
 What might be wrong ? (VS 2010)

```
namespace X  // not sent to interactive
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections
module M = 
  let square  (a _[]) = Array.map          (fun a ->  a*a ) // OK        
  let squareP (a:_[]) = Array.Parallel.map (fun a ->  a*a ) // Error: "Parallel" not defined
```

This code compiles fine in FSI but when part of a project fails:

`------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: DELETE TEST, Konfiguration: Debug Any CPU ------
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Debug\DELETE_TEST.dll -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\DELETE_TEST.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" -r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1031 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors Module1.fs 
    C:\work\Goswin\30_F#\16-135_LAD\DELETE TEST\Module1.fs(7,37): Fehler FS0039: Der Wert, Konstruktor, Namespace oder Typ "Parallel" ist nicht definiert.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting .NET 2.0: `-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll"`

The `Parallel` module is implemented via `System.Threading.Tasks`, which were not introduced until .NET 4.0.  Thus the `Parallel` module doesn't exist on `Array` in the .NET 2.0 version of FSharp.Core.dll.  If you re-target to 4.0 it will work.

It works in FSI because FSI runs in a .NET 4 environment.